# Using an $unwind Just Prior to an updateMany() in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregate

In my MongoDB/Node backend, I have a function that updates a date on a field titled `subscriptionEnd` based on subscription _ids that are passed in. It looks like this:

```
    try {
      db.collection('clients').updateMany(
       { "subscription._id": { $in: mongoArrSubscription } },
       { $set : {"subscription.$.subscriptionEnd": lastDayOfMonth } },
        function (err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
      });
      res.sendStatus(200);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

This works as is. However, as is, this will only target the first element in the "subscription" array. I realize now we have instances where there are two elements within the same array that may be passed in. So, my thought is to use `$unwind` within this function, to first $unwind the "subscription" array. I'm a little unclear on the syntax however, and if this is doable.

My unwind aggregation would look like this:

```
Client.aggregate( [ { $unwind : "$subscription" } ] );
```

Is there a way I can chain together this `$unwind` aggregation, so it happens just prior to the `updateMany()` within my try/catch block? What does that syntax look like? Do I chain the operations together, or do I pass the `$unwind` in as an argument to the `updateMany()` ?

I tried this, passing the $unwind operation in as the first parameter:

```
    try {
      db.collection('clients').updateMany( { $unwind : "$subscription" },
       { "subscription._id": { $in: mongoArrSubscription } },
       { $set : {"subscription.$.subscriptionEnd": lastDayOfMonth } },
        function (err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
      });
      res.sendStatus(200);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

... but it errors out:

> MongoError: Unknown modifier: $unwind

So maybe I need to do the aggregation $unwind first, as a separate operation, and then run the `updateMany()` ?

UPDATE: Someone pointed out that `$unwind` is not useable with `updateMany()`, so perhaps I need to do the `$unwind` operation first and separately, and then run my `updateMany()` operation?

Comment: what is your mongo server version ? run db.version() on shell

Comment: I know where you're going with this @Veeram :). At present we're not running 3.6, so I can't target multi array elements with the syntax available in 3.6. We're on 3.2.9.

Comment: aggregation is to read data, you can't really used it together with updateMany.

Comment: Use [bulk write](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @Veeram. From a cursory look it seems that $unwind is not one of the valid operations you can use with bulkWrite(). Did you mean use it in a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mimic the 3.6 multi update using aggregation and bulk write for lower versions.

Something like

```
var bulk = db.getCollection('clients').initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
var count = 0;
var batch = 1;

db.getCollection('clients').aggregate([
    {$match:{"subscription._id":{$in:mongoArrSubscription}}},
    {$unwind:"$subscription"},
    {$match:{"subscription._id":{$in:mongoArrSubscription}}},
    {$project: {_id:0, subscription_id:"$subscription._id"}}
]).forEach(function(doc){ 
    var subscription_id = doc.subscription_id;
    bulk.find({"subscription._id":subscription_id}).updateOne(
       {$set:{"subscription.$.subscriptionEnd": lastDayOfMonth}}
   ); 
    count++;  
    if (count == batch) { 
        bulk.execute(); 
        bulk = db.getCollection('clients').initializeUnorderedBulkOp(); 
        count = 0;
    } 
});

if (count > 0) { 
     bulk.execute(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Veeram, I will take a look at this.

Comment: I gave the query for mongo shell. Try `db.collection`